# Importing non-square tables in numpy

Tags: python, file-io, python-3.x, numpy

Using `numpy` in `python3.3`, can `genfromtxt` be used to import non-square tables? I want to read from a file that looks like this:

> title
>
> 2 1
>
> -0.6634   -0.3830   -0.0000 C
>
> 0.6634    0.3830   -0.0000 R
>
> 1 2  1  1

where each line ends with an `\n`. Clearly this table is not square. I haven't had success with `loadtxt` or `genfromtxt`. They both want square tables. Here are examples and their results:

```
>>> with open('propane.ct','r') as f:
       txt = f.read()
       data = np.genfromtxt(io.BytesIO(txt.encode()), delimiter='\n', dtype=None)

[b'propane.ct' b'3 2' b'-1.3268   ' b'0.0000    ' b'1.3268   -' b'1 2  1  1'
 b'2 3  1  1']
```

and

```
>>> np.loadtxt('propane.ct',skiprows=1)
array([[ 3.    ,  2.    ],
       [-1.3268, -0.383 ],
       [ 0.    ,  0.383 ],
       [ 1.3268, -0.383 ],
       [ 1.    ,  2.    ],
       [ 2.    ,  3.    ]])
```

or

```
>>> np.genfromtxt('propane.ct')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1638, in genfromtxt
    raise ValueError(errmsg)
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #2 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
    Line #3 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
    Line #4 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
    Line #5 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
    Line #6 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
    Line #7 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
```

The files are generated by proprietary software, so I cannot square the table during the initial file creation. I have thought of adding columns to each row so as to make it square, but this would probably be less efficient than using `numpy` built-ins.

Is there something I'm doing wrong or do I have to write my own parser?

Comment: The problem isn't so much about importing the file as it is with the fact that you're trying to store it as a numpy array, which requires uniform size in each dimension ("square").  The best you can probably do is a list of lists, or use another package.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.genfromtxt` setting the parameter `skip_header`, like:

```
np.genfromtxt('my_file.csv', skip_header=4, dtype=str)
#array([['-0.6634', '-0.3830', '-0.0000', 'C'],
#       ['0.6634', '0.3830', '-0.0000', 'R'],
#       ['1', '2', '1', '1']],
#      dtype='|S7')
```

Comment: Actually this might be very useful if I could do a `skip_footer` from the EOF up to a certain row. The number of rows to skip are bound to change.

Comment: Which I have just found can be done by `np.genfromtxt(itertools.islice(file,2),skip_header=1)`.